# When did Stack Overflow first go live?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange-history

When did Stack Overflow first go live?

Comment: Give some Badges for Annual Performance Awards on Tomorrow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) [announced the Stack Overflow private beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/) on July 31, 2008. It went public some time afterwards. The Stack Overflow blog was created long before as a communication method between Jeff Atwood and [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) and the audience and as a hosting ground for their podcasts.

Comment: Yearly badge is drawing nearer

Comment: Wow, has it almost been a year already?! Man how time flies.